# There is no holomorphic $f$ such that for all $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$, $f^2(z)=\sin z$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove doesn't exist function $f(z)$ which is analytic in neighborhood of $0$ (defined to be $S$) such that $\forall z\in S, f^2(z)=\sin z$.

I think that the argument principle (or Liouville theorem) should be used here but I don't know even from where to start. I'd be glad for a hint how to define my functions and general sense where the contradiction come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ with $f(0)=0$ and if $g(z)=f^2(z)$ then $g'(0)=0$. So, we cannot have $g(z)=\sin z$.

Comment: The zero that f get on S is a result of proof by contradiction that $f(z)=\sqrt{\sin (z)}$?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, when $g(z)=\sin z$ we have $g(0)=0$ that is $f^2(0)=0$ so $f(0)=0$. I wouldn't introduce $\sqrt{\sin z}$.

Comment: What's the problem with $\sqrt{\sin z}$? and thanks.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, What we prove in your question is that there is no valid, "*i.e.* analytic" definition of the square root of $\sin z$ in the neighborhood of $0$. $0$ is what we call a branch point for this function.